# Websockets - trying to convert Phython Code to Node

Tags: python, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to copy the features of this library https://github.com/rnbguy/pysphere/blob/master/misphere.py which connects via websockets to the Mi Sphere 360 camera.

The important code is here

```
ms_ip = '192.168.42.1'
ms_tcp_port = 7878
ms_uk_port = 8787
ms_fs_port = 50422

def init(self):
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    self.socket.connect((self.ms_ip, self.ms_tcp_port))
    self.socket_1 = socket.socket()
    self.recv_handle_live = True
    self.recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.recv_handler)
    self.recv_thread.daemon = True
    self.session = Session()
    self.session.conf = {}
    self.session.locks = {}
    self.last_send = 0
```

I'm trying to do this with the `ws` library in Node

```
const ip = '192.168.42.1'
const port = '7878'
const url = `ws://${ip}:${port}`
const websocket = new WebSocket(url)
```

However I'm not getting a connection to the camera.  (It's connected via Wifi, but the websocket never sends a connection message)

I'm wondering if it's to do with the protocols, which are listed in the Phython code.

I see in the websocket documentation you can define protocols in the connection, but I can't find any documentation about what those protocols are and how you add them.

i.e.

```
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```

Anyone know how I add something like this in the Node websocket connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A webSocket connection cannot be made to a plain TCP socket server.

A plain TCP socket is not the same as a webSocket.  Your Python code appears to be making a plain TCP socket connection.

Your node.js code is attempting to make a webSocket connection.  A webSocket connection can only be made to a webSocket server that speaks the webSocket protocol (which runs on top of a plain TCP socket).

If your Python code is working, then you apparently need to make just a plain TCP socket connection which you can see how to do in the [Net module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

For further description of the differences between a plain TCP connection and a webSocket connection see these:

[Computer refuses websocket connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999626/computer-refuses-websocket-connections/49000773#49000773)

[What's the difference between WebSocket and plain socket communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480575/whats-the-difference-between-websocket-and-plain-socket-communication/28491729#28491729)

[Is there a way to do a tcp connection to an IP with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682481/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-tcp-connection-to-an-ip-with-javascript/34688171#34688171)

[Socket server not connect with JavaScript socket client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747699/socket-server-not-connect-with-javascript-socket-client/38749538#38749538)

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a regular TCP socket, use `net` package instead of a WebSocket. Example Node equivalent code:

```js
const net = require('net');
const port = 7878
const ip = "192.168.42.1"

const socket = net.createConnection(port, ip);

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("socket connected");
});
```